# Can I show the Error Handling in same page ? ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, error-handling, asp.net-core-mvc

I can control the errors with Error Handling but show a different page.

Example:

[image]

But this is not my page, I want this error in there in this layout:

[image]

And this is my code:

Startup.cs:

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error/{0}");
}
```

ErrorController.cs;

```
[Route("Error/{statusCode}")]
public IActionResult HttpStatusCodeHandler(int statusCode)
{
    var statusCodeResult = HttpContext.Features.Get<IStatusCodeReExecuteFeature>();

    switch (statusCode)
    {
        case 404:
                ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Sorry, the page you requested could not be found";
                ViewBag.Path = statusCodeResult.OriginalPath;
                ViewBag.QS = statusCodeResult.OriginalQueryString;
                //ViewBag.StatusCode = statusCode;
                break;
    }

    return View("Index");
}

[Route("Error")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult Error()
{
    var exceptionDetails = HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();
    ViewBag.ExceptionPath = exceptionDetails.Path;
    ViewBag.ExceptionMessage = exceptionDetails.Error.Message;
    ViewBag.StackTrace = exceptionDetails.Error.StackTrace;

    return View("Error");
}
```

Error.cshtml;

```
<h3>
Exception Details:
</h3>

<div class="alert alert-danger">
<h5>Exception Path</h5>
<hr />
<p>@ViewBag.ExceptionPath</p>
</div>

<div class="alert alert-danger">
<h5>Exception Message</h5>
<hr />
<p>@ViewBag.ExceptionMessage</p>
</div>

<div class="alert alert-danger">
<h5>Exception Stack Trace</h5>
<hr />
<p>@ViewBag.ExceptionStackTrace</p>
</div>
```

How can I show errors in different layouts?

Comment: Are you wanting the error(s) to show in the current page or route to a custom error page?

Comment: @Demodave I want the current page.

Answer (score 0):

Well yes, you can use your layout page if you want by adding this to the Error page

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_YourLayoutPage.cshtml";
}
```

There is something to consider though - what *if* the error occurs within your layout page?

You can also catch your errors and display them on the page itself (during execution), but you'll need to catch the errors you might expect and display those. The error you provide as example is *not* an error you expect, so this error does belong to it's specific error page

Comment: I got HTTP ERROR 500 this way.

Comment: Hence the "what if the error occurs within your layout page?"